# CruiseControl.NET MSTest not overwriting trx file

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to show the results of visual studio unit tests within CruiseControl. Here is the relevant part of my config:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe
    C:\Build\Test\TestCases\
    /testcontainer:H4Test\bin\debug\H4Test.dll /runconfig:localtestrun.Testrunconfig /resultsfile:H4Test\H4Results.trx
    900
  


  
    
      C:\Build\Test\TestCases\H4Test\H4Results.trx

The issue is that the H4Results.trx can only be created once, so every subsequent run just shows the results of the first run of the test cases. I need to specify the name so that I can do the merge command. How do I get this working?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer, creating a bat file to delete the .trx each run:

http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/bm-bloggers/archive/2006/06/14/5255.aspx